# linux mint xdotool type web link

Tags: linux-mint, xdotool

I am trying to use `xdotool` to type a URL and instead of:

```
https://www.sample.com/sales/search?facet=T&facetT=45259587&facet.T=44143327&facet.T=25866782&facet.T=260287
```

I get:

```
https;//www.sample.com/sales/search/facet=t7facet.t=452595877facet.t=441433277facet.t=258667827facet.t=260287127facet
```

You can see that `&` has changed to `7`, `:` to `;`, as well as other issues.

My `xdotool` version is `3.20150503.1`. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Could you please provide the full command that you are issuing with `xdotool`?

Comment: xdotool type --window windowid "link string"

Comment: Then what system configurations should I check, or where to look for an answer to my problem?